# Is the Hamiltonian the only quantum observable with a mixed spectrum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, mathematical-physics, hamiltonian

Let $\mathscr{H}$ be a complex separable Hilbert space of a quantum system. Assume that the Groenewold-van Hove no-go theorem did not necessarily apply and we are free to map all possible polynomial Hamiltonian observables on the classical phase space into self-adjoint operators on $\mathscr{H}$. We can also include spin "by hand".

Is the following true? (the converse statement is not at all easily proved for the Hydrogen atom, for example).

$$ A = f\left(x_{i},p_{i},S_{i}\right) \text{is self-adjoint with a mixed spectrum (*)} \\ \Rightarrow A\equiv H \left(x_{i},p_{i},S_{i}\right) ("the ~Hamiltonian")$$

(*) A self-adjoint operator on a complex separable Hilbert space is said to possess a mixed spectrum iff $\sigma_{pp} \neq \emptyset$ and $\sigma_{c} \neq \emptyset $.

**Further note**: the identification as the Hamiltonian is up to a trivial combination $cH+d\hat{1}$ which preserves the spectral properties of $H$.

Comment: Perhaps a silly question: If $H$ has a mixed spectrum, doesn't $f(H)$ as well for some $f$ that doesn't map the discrete parts into the continuous ones?

Comment: An extension of @ACuriousMind's comment: take absolutely any observable $X$ whose spectrum has a continuous part, and consider the observable $f(X)$, where the function $f$ rounds some parts of the spectrum to the nearest integer. This gives an endless supply of observables with mixed spectra, and they're all just as realistic (just as measurable) as the original observables were.